# Is a way to show multiple metrics on Google Data Studio Geo Map?

Tags: looker-studio, tableau-api

I'm trying to use Google Data Studio (GDS) to display a dashboard with a map. I want to show 2 metrics on the tooltip - *Number of Trips* and *Number of Customers*. But GDS lets me select only one metric at a time as the default and makes everything else optional. Is there a way to show both metrics **simultaneously**?

I'm able to show both metrics on the map using Tableau Public. However, I would prefer staying within the Google ecosystem, if possible.

For reference, I've attached a screenshot below - comparing the two visualizations.

[image: Screenshot of tooltip in Tableau Public vs GDS Maps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geo Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037) in Google Data Studio currently only display a single metric at a time (no optional or additional tooltips for Geo Maps at the moment).

However, as alluded to, [Optional Metrics](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9484925) would allow viewers to choose a single metric from a range of different metrics.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/83504e92-e2e7-4b59-86b5-74ebbbbd5fdf) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]